# Mahout K Means clustering input file format

Tags: hadoop, format, mahout, k-means

I am trying to use Mahout to run a K Means cluster algorithm. I don't know how to format the input file. The base data that I have in a table is a user id, followed by several hundred values. I know I need to supply input as a vector, can someone share the format of this please.

For example:

```
User Nbr_of_tweets Total_spend Gender Home_ownership email_on_file transaction_count
A     20              $30        Male   Owns a home       Y                  5
B     10             $400      Female    Rents            N                 20
....
```

Would it simply be:

A:20,30,0,0,1,5

B:10,400,1,1,0,20

I'm coding:

1. Male as 0, Female as 1 and
2. Owns a home as 0, Rents as 1
3. Y as 1, N as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new with Mahout and I faced the same issue. I finally found an example on the mahout website about applying clustering (k-means is also my target) on your kind of that, that is also mine (https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/clustering-of-synthetic-control-data.html).
Basically, your file should be in this format (I just put 0 and 1 as example).

```
1 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 0
...
```

Each record in your case should be a user (in mine each record is an output from a machine).
To run the K-means I am using the command suggested in the website but the result is a set of centroids, if I understood well, not a set of clusterized data.

Remember that the input must be stored in the HDFS file system whereas the output is saved in the local file system (just to avoid struggling in finding the output file as I did :-))

Hope this can help you.